# Unable to load LESS file in VueJs as Global LESS file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack-2

I have installed LESS as below in my VueJs

> npm install -D less less-loader

My Webpack config `webpack.base.conf.js`, I have added below code in `module -> rules`

```
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
              "vue-style-loader",
              "css-loader",
              "less-loader"
            ]
          }
```

in my `src/main.js` I am importing the `LESS` file like this.

> import "../static/css/style.less";

`style.less` contains only 1 line

> @white-color: #eeeeee;

---

**Error build failed:**

```
    // load the styles
    var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{\"minimize\":false,\"sourceMap\":false}!../../node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{\"sourceMap\":false}!./style.less");
```

[Image for complete information about Build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ld8S.png)

Comment: Try string https://gitlab.com/snippets/1666860#L37

Comment: @Piterden do you mean to use `loader: 'style!css!less'` like this?

Comment: @Piterden I tried, but there is a different issue my less is not found..

Comment: give us a link to a repository with your code, please

Comment: @Piterden Issue can reproduce here: https://github.com/2rohith2/vuejsLessError please use this repo.

Comment: What if remove `!!` ?